# Sharing x-axis labels in a horizontal plotly subplot figure

Tags: r, plotly, subplot

I have a list of figures created with `R`'s `plotly`, just as an example:

```
library(plotly)
library(dplyr)

set.seed(1)
data.df <- data.frame(val = c(rnorm(100,0,1),rnorm(100,1,1)), group = c(rep("A",100),rep("B",100)))
density.df <- do.call(rbind,lapply(levels(data.df$group),function(g){
  dens <- density(dplyr::filter(data.df,group == g)$val)
  data.frame(x = dens$x, y = dens$y, group = g)
}))

plot.list <- lapply(1:5,function(x)
  plot_ly(x = density.df$x, y = density.df$y, type = 'scatter', mode = 'lines',color = density.df$group, showlegend = (x == 5)) %>%
    layout(xaxis = list(title= "Value", zeroline = F), yaxis = list(title = "Density", zeroline = F))
  )
```

Which I'd like to put together horizontally, where there will be only a single shared x-axis label and a single shared y-axis label.

I'm using:

```
plotly::subplot(plot.list, nrows = 1, shareX = T, shareY = T, titleX = T, titleY = T)
```

And getting:

[image]

Is it not possible to get a single x-axis label in a horizontal plot?

The same occurs for the y-axis label if I change the `nrows` argument value from 1 to 5.

Answer (score 0):

You can manually add an annotation

https://community.plot.ly/t/subplots-how-to-add-master-axis-titles/13927/5

```
myplotly(df) %>%
    add_annotations(
        text = "my x title",
        x = 0.5,
        y = 0,
        yref = "paper",
        xref = "paper",
        xanchor = "center",
        yanchor = "bottom",
        yshift = -35,
        showarrow = FALSE,
        font = list(size = 15)
    )
```